# iOS navigation bar custom titleView subviews are not showing properly

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

iOS navigation bar custom titleView subviews are not showing properly when the parent viewController pushed from another view controller.

Custom Title view in root view
[image]

Custom Title view in View controller after pushing from the different view controller

[image]

Code I tried for Custom TitleView

```
   let height = CGFloat(500)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: view.frame.width, height: height)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .blue
    let navView = UIImageView()
    navView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width-100, height: height)
    navView.backgroundColor = .red
    navigationItem.titleView = navView
```

Suview

```
        let oneLabel = UILabel()
        oneLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: navView.frame.size.height-13, width: 26, height: 26)
        oneLabel.text = "1"
        oneLabel.textColor = .white
        oneLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: Constants.greenColor)
        oneLabel.textAlignment = .center
        navView.addSubview(oneLabel)

        oneLabel.clipsToBounds = true
        oneLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 13
```

Comment: why your navigation bar heigh is 500?

Comment: @Code cracker here: oneLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: navView.frame.size.height-13, width: 26, height: 26), Why you subtract `navView.frame.size.height-13` in `Y` position? I think you just set like `44 / 2 = 22` on there.

Answer (score 0):

The total height of the label is 26 and u have reduced only 13 from the imageview's height which shows half of the label.. Make your y value of label something like 
y: navView.frame.size.height - 30